# Rails API response body is string not json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I have the following REST API call in my code which if wrong returns this error

```
def get_token 
  responseObject = {
      message: "Error",
      errors: ["User does not exist"]
  }

  render status: 403, json: responseObject
end
```

Problem is in my response.json(), i get this instead 
[image]

So when i try to do this in my code response.json().errors, i always get undefined because somehow it doesnt see my response in my body as json.

Actually not sure how to solve this mess.

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks no problem, the response is as expected. So can you give more information about where do you parsing your JSON response (the place you do `response.json().errors`)? Is it a Javascript client? Is it jQuery AJAX?

Comment: @yeuem1vannam it is a javascript client. i did response.json().errors and i got undefined.

Comment: @KingsleySimon It really depends on what JS client you are using. Each one has different response schema. In the case of response error message in the body, I see that there is no problem with your server-side code. Can you give us the name of JS client you are using?

Comment: angular2 actually

Comment: So I think it is actually `response.json().data.errors`

Comment: @KingsleySimon can u try this way `render json: {error: responseObject}.to_json` or `render json: {errors: responseObject}, status: :unprocessable_entity`. Also, probably yr ajax call is wrong, share that part...